# Button color for access and deny permissions buttons?

Tags: color, email, color-combination, button

I need to create an email template which is auto generated when an user requests access permissions to a document .The email template is sent to the document owner and is in this format :

Subject: Request for access ---title of document---

```
Hi,

      --placeholder for alias-- is requesting access to document --title of document--.Please click on the links below to either allow or deny the user access.

         <placeholder for grant permissions>        <Placeholder for deny permissions>

Thank you.

---RBI content publishing platform ---

Please note: this is an auto generated e-mail that cannot receive replies.
```

So I have two questions:

a) Are there default colors which should be used for the grant and deny access permissions buttons ?I was thinking of green and red respectively but I just would like to know if there is any color which is normally used

b) What is the order in which the buttons should be placed ?

Comment: c) Should email even contain 'buttons'?

Comment: @DA01 ,I was thinking of having links only but then isn't there  a possibility that the person might miss those links completely since they would merge would the rest of the email except for the blue link color.I felt having two buttons would make it easier to see the options and decide. (the person receiving this email could be getting several times as for every access request,a new email is generated)

Comment: hard for me to say with any real data. I'd suggest user testing. That said, links in emails is more than common. I prefer to try the simple option first when in doubt (that being a link.)

Comment: Thanks ,we dont really have an option of user testing this for now but I'll look at that option too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) The colors that you mentioned are the best known for Yes/Accept/Grant access (Green) and No/Decline/Reject (Red).

b) The order should be Green then Red.

Also @melee has a very good point, if you are not interested in gathering audit information on how many accepted/declined a request your good to go with a green button of accept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a "deny permissions" button is even necessary - if they do not act on the email, then no permissions are granted. Why not just present the "Grant Permissions" option with copy stating to ignore the message otherwise?

Comment: ,thanks for the response ,we need to keep track of which all users were denied access,hence the need for an deny permissions button. This is needed to prevent the user from requesting permissions again and again (since every permission request auto generates an email)

Comment: I see. You could still do that with a pending request flag, though.